# No mouse events are triggered after upgrading to Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am about ready to tear my hair out. I have a fairly complex custom Silverlight control where some of it is defined in XAML and the rest of the controls are added programatically. The problem is that none of my mouse events are being fired at this point.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="itiStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <!--L O A D I N G  A R E A-->
        <Storyboard x:Name="LoadingArea_Loading" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="spinner" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="43200" Duration="00:03:00" />
        </Storyboard>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" x:Key="TransparentBackground">
         </SolidColorBrush>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowBigImage">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="ImageZoom"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="00:00:02" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HideBigImage">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="ImageZoom"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="00:00:01" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowFadedBackground">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="LoadingAreaBg"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="00:00:02" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HideFadedBackground">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="LoadingAreaBg"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="00:00:01" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowTestFeedback">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="TestFeedback"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="00:00:02" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HideTestFeedback">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="TestFeedback"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="00:00:01" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowAnswerResponse">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="AnswerResponse"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HideAnswerResponse">
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetName="AnswerResponse"
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="1.0" To="0.0" BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,38,0,0" Name="m_txtNoQuestionPools" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <MediaElement Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,192,0,0" Name="_audio" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
        <Grid Height="498" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="m_oQuestionPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="QuestionHeight" Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition x:Name="AnswerHeight" Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="ImageZoom" Width="450" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0" Canvas.ZIndex="999" />
            <StackPanel Height="100" Name="questionPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="743" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Name="questionTextBlock" />
                <Image Name="questionImage"  Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="743" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid Height="Auto" Name="AnswerContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="743">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Canvas Height="Auto" Width="743" Background="{StaticResource TransparentBackground}" x:Name="LoadingAreaBg" Canvas.ZIndex="998" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Collapsed" >                            
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas Height="61" Width="61" Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="8" x:Name="LoadingArea" Canvas.ZIndex="999" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Path x:Name="Pathb" Width="61.3707" Height="61.3717" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.33333" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#BD006EBA" Fill="#BD000000" Data="F1 M 303.297,179.655C 303.297,196.234 289.854,209.673 273.271,209.673C 256.7,209.673 243.26,196.234 243.26,179.655C 243.26,163.075 256.7,149.635 273.271,149.635C 289.854,149.635 303.297,163.075 303.297,179.655 Z "/>
                        <Path x:Name="Path_0b" Width="50.0575" Height="50.0615" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF446485" Data="F1 M 256.314,179.655C 256.314,170.297 263.923,162.687 273.272,162.687C 282.634,162.687 290.244,170.297 290.244,179.655C 290.244,189.01 282.634,196.621 273.272,196.621C 263.923,196.621 256.314,189.01 256.314,179.655 Z M 248.25,179.655C 248.25,193.456 259.479,204.686 273.272,204.686C 279.962,204.686 286.249,202.081 290.976,197.354C 295.704,192.626 298.307,186.341 298.307,179.655C 298.307,172.968 295.704,166.683 290.976,161.956C 286.249,157.227 279.962,154.624 273.272,154.624C 259.479,154.624 248.25,165.851 248.25,179.655 Z " Canvas.Left="5.5" Canvas.Top="5.498"/>
                        <Path x:Name="spinner" Width="24.9508" Height="25.0417" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 256.314,179.655L 256.314,179.64L 248.25,179.64L 248.25,179.655C 248.25,193.432 259.44,204.643 273.2,204.681L 273.2,196.617C 263.885,196.578 256.314,188.986 256.314,179.655 Z " RenderTransformOrigin="1,0" Canvas.Left="5.472" Canvas.Top="30.507">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.801298,0.928042" EndPoint="0.159004,0.00604094">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF446185" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFE400" Offset="0.543967"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF2DB21" Offset="0.981595"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF4DD23" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                        <Path x:Name="Path_2b" Width="44.9978" Height="45.0008" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.66667" StrokeMiterLimit="2" Stroke="#5AFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 294.444,179.655C 294.444,191.344 284.967,200.821 273.272,200.821C 261.588,200.821 252.113,191.344 252.113,179.655C 252.113,167.965 261.588,158.487 273.272,158.487C 284.967,158.487 294.444,167.965 294.444,179.655 Z " Canvas.Left="8.002" Canvas.Top="8"/>
                        <Path x:Name="Path_3b" Width="42.3312" Height="42.3342" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#B3000000" Data="F1 M 294.444,179.655C 294.444,191.344 284.967,200.821 273.272,200.821C 261.588,200.821 252.113,191.344 252.113,179.655C 252.113,167.965 261.588,158.487 273.272,158.487C 284.967,158.487 294.444,167.965 294.444,179.655 Z " Canvas.Left="9.5" Canvas.Top="9.5"/>
                    </Canvas>                        
                    <sdk:Label Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Canvas.ZIndex="999" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0" Name="AnswerResponse" Foreground="White"/>
                    <sdk:Label Height="50" FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.ZIndex="999" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0" Name="TestFeedback" Foreground="White" />
                    <ScrollViewer Name="AnswerScrollPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel Name="answerPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="743"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Grid Height="Auto" Name="answerGrid" Width="Auto" Margin="20" Background="Transparent" Canvas.ZIndex="998">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="40" MinWidth="40" Width="40" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="35" MinWidth="35" Width="35" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="35" MinWidth="35" Width="35" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="35" MinWidth="35" Width="35" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="35" MinWidth="35" Width="35" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition  MinWidth="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBox Name = "m_answerItem" Width="Auto" Padding="20" Visibility="Collapsed" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.ZIndex="2" />
                            <Grid x:Name="RankOrderControls" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="370" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="m_RankOrderRow" Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <controlsToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="m_rankOrderSource" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                    <ListBox x:Name="m_rankOrderAvailable" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    </ListBox>
                                </controlsToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Height="15" Text="Drag your choices below to rank" Width="370" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <controlsToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget x:Name="m_rankOrderTarget" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                        <it:ListBoxGeneric x:Name="mRankOrderUsed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                            <it:ListBoxGeneric.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </it:ListBoxGeneric.ItemsPanel>
                                        </it:ListBoxGeneric>
                                    </controlsToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>        
</Canvas>
```

Code that generates the radio buttons:

```
private FrameworkElement AddRadioButton(string answerIdentifiers)
    {
        var oRadioButton = new RadioButton
                               {
                                   Content = answerIdentifiers,
                                   Background =
                                       new SolidColorBrush(ColorNamesExtensions.ColorNames.Transparent.FromName())                                       
                               };
        oRadioButton.Click += OQuestionControlClick;
        oRadioButton.MouseEnter += ORadioButtonMouseEnter;
        oRadioButton.MouseLeave += ORadioButtonMouseLeave;
        return oRadioButton;
    }
```

Code that creates the new grid row:

```
var row = new RowDefinition();                
            answerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
```

Code that adds the element to the grid:

```
private void AddToGrid(FrameworkElement element, int columnNumber, int rowNumber)
    {
        answerGrid.Children.Add(element);
        Grid.SetColumn(element, columnNumber);
        Grid.SetRow(element, rowNumber - 1);
    }
```

The reason I am dealing with raw framework elements is that I could be adding radio buttons or checkboxes or anything that extends FrameworkElement to the grid.

Again, this code worked fine in SL4, and it still displays fine in SL5, but none of the mouse events are triggered.

I've tried the transparent backgrounds and ensuring things have sizes, I've tried messing with the z-order and I've tried messing with IsHitTestEnabled and nothing seems to be working.

Any help?

EDIT: I've also updated all of target versions to 5.0 from 4.0 and everything builds fine with that configuration.

Comment: try to subscribe via AddHandler, so that you can receive handled events as well

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh397894%28v=vs.95%29?

Comment: There are known changes relating to mouse support (multiple click detection), but that shouldn't cause what you get :(

Comment: one more thing. Try to explore runtime visual tree with some tool like Silverlight Spy. Maybe something is placed over your elements and catches mouse input (you use ZIndex so I think it's possible).

Comment: I've tried silverlight spy, but the way I load the application (in a lightbox) it doesn't recognize the actual application. I'll fiddle with that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: notacat: I tried that as well, it's never being registered even with addhandler

Comment: you can sort it out without Silverlight Spy. Try to remove or comment all but answerGrid and remove all ZIndex settings. If you can get your code working with very simple visual tree, you can add/uncomment outer ScrollViewer and test again, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out thanks to getting Silverlight Spy. In Silverlight 4, Borders weren't marked as HitTestVisible, but apparently in Silverlight 5 they are. This isn't documented anywhere but the borders were taking all of the mouse events and handling them.

I set HitTestVisible to False on all of the Borders in MainPage.xaml and now all mouse events are working as expected.